# Arduino with XBee Series 1 and Wireless SD Shield, Receive Data

Tags: c++, arduino, xbee

I have an issue when trying to get data to my xbee connected to an Arduino Arduino Wireless SD Shield, not recivo data, this is my code.

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); // opens serial port, sets data rate to 9600 bps
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() >0) {
    byte temp= Serial.read();
    Serial.print(temp);
  }
}
```

I connect the XBee to a plate and see that XCTU and receipt data, but using the Arduino UNO and Arduino Wireless SD Shield does not work I do not get anything, please aid that could be wrong?

I am sending data from another xbee connected to a PIC 16F877A using a 9600 baud rate on both sides.

This images:

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Answer (score 1):

I've run this setup lots of times in my lab and we need to break down your troubleshooting into some smaller steps.

The first thing to do is validate the the XBEE radios are sending traffic.

After you have verified the XBEE link then you can troubleshoot the connection between the XBEE and the Arduino.

In order to troubleshoot the XBEE you are going to want to plug the XBEE directly into your computer.  I use this shield to attach my XBEE to the USB port on a computer and directly monitor the traffic it is receiving.

https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11812

If you'd prefer a different vendor there are lots of simple XBEE to USB boards that do the same function.

Let's get that set up and then once you do, I'll help you troubleshoot the Arduino if it still isn't working.